# How to add a new property to a class using class decorator?

Tags: typescript

How can I add a new property to a class using a class decorator?

Code for example:

```
@MyClassDecorator
class MyClass {
    myFirstName: string;
    myLastName: string;
}

// I need something like this:
function MyClassDecorator (target: any): any {
    target['myNickname'] = 'Gambler';
}

let myClass = new MyClass();
console.log(myClass['myNickname']); // expecting "Gambler" but got "undefined"
```

How to fix this code?

Is it possible at all to add a property to a class using decorator?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add the property to the prototype and not the constructor:

```
function MyClassDecorator(target: any): any {
    target.prototype.myNickname = "Gambler";
}
```

That will get you what you want, but the problem is that you won't be able to access this property without typescript complaining:

```
let myClass = new MyClass();
console.log(myClass.myNickname); // error: Property 'myNickname' does not exist on type 'MyClass'
```

You can try something like:

```
function myClassFactory(): MyClass & { myNickname: string } {
    return new MyClass() as MyClass & { myNickname: string };
}

let myClass = myClassFactory();
console.log(myClass.myNickname); // all good
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%40MyClassDecorator%0Aclass%20MyClass%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20myFirstName%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20myLastName%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%2F%2F%20I%20need%20something%20like%20this%3A%0Afunction%20MyClassDecorator(target%3A%20any)%3A%20any%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20target.prototype.myNickname%20%3D%20%22Gambler%22%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20myClassFactory()%3A%20MyClass%20%26%20%7B%20myNickname%3A%20string%20%7D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20new%20MyClass()%20as%20MyClass%20%26%20%7B%20myNickname%3A%20string%20%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20myClass%20%3D%20myClassFactory()%3B%0Aconsole.log(myClass.myNickname)%3B%20%2F%2F%20all%20good))

Comment: It works! Thanx a lot! My mistake is - I supposed it should be used some special approach to do this :)))

Comment: I used this approach with an angular component and it worked great until I tried to do a release build which does a full compile and then you get all kinds of property does not exist errors

Comment: @Simon_Weaver I'm going to need to see your code to understand why

Comment: It’s basically identical to what you have - i want to add a property to an angular component to be used by the html. I then reference the property within the component html which works, but when it does a publish build it runs more checks and they fail because the property doesn’t really exist as far as the compiler is concerned. I was just trying to be clever but I can just as easily achieve what I want by adding the property manually.

Comment: @Simon_Weaver Adding the property manually is the right thing to do IMO. Decorators are best for static things, It's also more clear for humans who read the code, not just for the compiler.