# How to add a new property or method to a class using decorator?

Tags: typescript, decorator

Basically [same question as this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41000670/how-to-add-a-new-property-to-a-class-using-class-decorator). But few more requirements.

1. How to add a new property/method to a class using **property** decorator instead of **class** decorator?
2. Critical is - **how to do this in a typesafe way automatically?** Can TypeScript support inferring added key? In an [earlier example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41000670/how-to-add-a-new-property-to-a-class-using-class-decorator), we had to manually add the type information. Is it possible for TypeScript to infer it?

An Example:

```
class HeaderComponent extends Vue {

    // @Stream$ should add key teanantId$ to class?
    @Stream$((store) => store.urlState.tenantId)
    public tenantId: number;
}
```

This is how it should work:

```
const a = new HeaderComponent();

// works
a.tenant;

// CAN THIS WORK?
a.tenantId$;
```

Answer (score 0):

Class decorator mutation currently [is not supported](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881) in TypeScript.

Decorated class needs merged declaration to define new properties explicitly:

```
interface HeaderComponent {
    tenantId$: Observable<number>;
}
class HeaderComponent extends Vue {
    @Stream$((store) => store.urlState.tenantId)
    public tenantId: number;
}
```

Since `tenantId$` property name is a result of runtime calculation, there is no chance that its inference  will be possible in future.