# Is it possible to type properties added by a decorator?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Let's say I have a decorator like in the following
[example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20withName(name)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(target)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20target.prototype.name%20%3D%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%40withName('Karl')%0Aclass%20Person%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20greet()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22Hi%20i%20am%20%22%2C%20this.name)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Aconst%20karl%20%3D%20new%20Person()%3B%0Akarl.greet()%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log(karl.name)%3B)
which adds a new `name` property with a preset value.

Is there any way to tell typescript that my decorator adds this property so that all decorated classes are typed correctly?

Example code:

```
function withName(name) {
    return (target) => {
        target.prototype.name = name;
    }
}

@withName('Karl')
class Person {
    greet() {
        console.log("Hi I'm ", this.name);
  }    
}


const karl = new Person();
karl.greet(); // Will log: "Hi I'm Karl"

console.log(karl.name); // <- Will cause a TypeScript error: "Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Person'"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a new property to a class using class decorator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41000670/how-to-add-a-new-property-to-a-class-using-class-decorator)

Comment: @jonrsharpe While that question is very, very similar that answer was provided long before mixin support existed in TS, we can do better now.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir that doesn't make it not a duplicate; it would be better to put the newer answer on the existing question so all of the information is in one place.

Answer (score 3):

Decorators by design are not allowed to change the structure of the type they are decorating. A supported way of doing this would be to use a mixin, as described [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/13743)

```
function withName(nameValue: string) {
    return <T extends new (...args: any[]) => any>(target: T) => {
        return class extends target {
            name: string = nameValue
        }
    }
}
const Person = withName("Karl")(class {
    greet() {
        console.log("Hi I'm ...");
    }
});
const karl = new Person();
console.log(karl.name);
```

The approach above only augments the class to the outside world so the added members are not visible from inside the class. We could augment the base class of `Person` (or use an empty class if there is no base class) to get access to the added fields inside the augmented class:

```
class Person extends withName("Karl")(class { }) {
    greet() {
        console.log("Hi I'm ", this.name);
    }
}

const karl = new Person();
karl.greet(); // Will log: "Hi I'm Karl"
```