# Mixin as class decorator in TypeScript does not update class property

Tags: typescript, decorator, mixins

### Intro

I have a project in TS that requires some classes to implement the following interface:

```
interface IStylable {
  readonly styles: {
    [property: string]: string
  };
  addStyles (styles: { [property: string]: string }): void;
  updateStyles (styles: { [property: string]: string }): void;
  removeStyles (styles: Array<string>): void;
}
```

To avoid boilerplate code I decided to create a [Mixin](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html) and apply it in each class I need it. (I could use an abstract class but my problem requires multiple inheritance solution, something that is not offered by TS.) Bellow is the class implementation of `IStylable` interface:

```
export class StylableClass implements IStylable {
  private readonly _styles: { [property: string]: string } = {};

  // For each property provided in styles param, check if the property
  // is not already present in this._styles and add it. This way we
  // do not overide existing property values.
  public addStyles (styles: { [property: string]: string }): void {
    for (const [property, value] of Object.entries(styles)) {
      if (!this._styles.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        this._styles[property] = value;
      }
    }
  }

  // For each property provided in styles param, check if the property
  // is already present in this._styles and add it. This way we
  // do add property values values that do not exist.
  public updateStyles (styles: { [property: string]: string }): void {
    for (const [property, value] of Object.entries(styles)) {
      if (this._styles.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        this._styles[property] = value;
      }
    }
  }

  // For each property in styles param, check if it is present in this._styles
  // and remove it.
  public removeStyles (styles: Array<string>): void {
    for (const property of styles) {
      if (this._styles.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        delete this._styles[property];
      }
    }
  }

  public set styles (styles: { [property: string]: string }) {
    this.addStyles(styles);
  }

  public get styles (): { [property: string]: string } {
    return this._styles;
  }
}
```

For something I'm really excited about and looking forward is standardized of decorator specification in ES6. Typescript allow this experimental feature by setting the `experimentalDecorators` flag in `tsconfig.json`. I wanted the `StylableClass` to be used as a class decorator (`@Stylable`) to make the code cleaner, so I created a function that takes a class and transforms it to decorator:

```
export function makeDecorator (decorator: Function) {
  return function (decorated: Function) {
    const fieldCollector: { [key: string]: string } = {};
    decorator.apply(fieldCollector);
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(fieldCollector).forEach((name) => {
      decorated.prototype[name] = fieldCollector[name];
    });

    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(decorator.prototype).forEach((name) => {
      decorated.prototype[name] = decorator.prototype[name];
    });
  };
}
```

and used it like so:

```
export const Stylable = () => makeDecorator(StylableClass);
```

### The problem

Now it's time for Unit testing. I created a dummy class to apply my decorator and wrote a simple test for `addStyles()` method.

```
@Stylable()
class StylableTest {
  // Stylable
  public addStyles!: (styles: {
    [prop: string]: string;
  }) => void;

  public updateStyles!: (styles: {
    [prop: string]: string;
  }) => void;

  public removeStyles!: (styles: string[]) => void;

  public styles: { [property: string]: string } = {};
}

describe('Test Stylable mixin', () => {
  it('should add styles', () => {
    const styles1 = {
      float: 'left',
      color: '#000'
    };

    const styles2 = {
      background: '#fff',
      width: '100px'
    };

    // 1
    const styles = new StylableTest();
    expect(styles.styles).to.be.an('object').that.is.empty;

    // 2
    styles.addStyles(styles1);
    expect(styles.styles).to.eql(styles1);

    // 3
    styles.addStyles(styles2);
    expect(styles.styles).to.eql(Object.assign({}, styles1, styles2));
  });
});
```

The problem is that the second expect statement fails. After executing `styles.addStyles(styles1);` the `styles.styles` array is still empty when it should contain the `styles1` object. When I debugged my code I found that the `push` statement in `addStyles()` method is executed as expected, thus the loop is not problematic, but the array is not updated after the execution of the method ends. Can you provide me a hint or a solution on what did I missed? The first thing I checked is maybe something is going wrong with the `makeDecorator` function but as long as I can execute the methods I cannot find some other clue to look for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `StylableClass` mixin declares a property called `styles`. But the `StylableTest` creates a  field name `styles` and assigns an empty object to it which nobody is going to use. You need to transfer the property descripts from the decorator to the target class, and remove the `= {}` from the `styles` in `StylableTest`:

```
function makeDecorator(decorator) {
    return function (decorated) {
        var fieldCollector = {};
        decorator.apply(fieldCollector);
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(fieldCollector).forEach(function (name) {
            decorated.prototype[name] = fieldCollector[name];
        });
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(decorator.prototype).forEach(function (name) {
            var descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(decorator.prototype, name);
            if (descriptor) {
                Object.defineProperty(decorated.prototype, name, descriptor);
            }
            else {
                decorated.prototype[name] = decorator.prototype[name];
            }
        });
    };
}
```

May I suggest a [less error prone approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50943370/is-it-possible-to-type-properties-added-by-a-decorator/50943841#50943841) to mixins in typescript. This approach o having to redeclare all the mixin members will cause errors later down the road. At least avoid restating the type of the fields using type queries:

```
@Stylable()
class StylableTest {
    // Stylable
    public addStyles!: IStylable['addStyles']

    public updateStyles!: IStylable['updateStyles']

    public removeStyles!: IStylable['removeStyles']

    public styles!: IStylable['styles']
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. In the end this is the approach I follow.

Comment: @GeorgeGkasdrogkas It's you call :) Type queries will still help you write less (and keep the types in sync automatically), and the `defineProperty` fix should make it work.

Comment: do you believe that the approach with `makeDecorator` is worth?

Comment: @GeorgeGkasdrogkas In what sense worth it ? Having the mixin makes sense. If your going to create more mixins `makeDecorator` is a decent way to copy fields/properties/methods over to the decorated class and is code you would need to write for each mixin otherwise. So yes it makes sense :)

Comment: I moved to TypeScript to be able to get better support in terms of types. I still learning  TS and understand that some ways are better than others. In the end, if you do not set the types correctly you might face huge problems afterward.

Comment: @GeorgeGkasdrogkas Yes, that is true, that is why I recommended at lest using type queries to not have to re-specify the types which would be tedious and error prone. And using the build-in way of doing mix-ins you don't have the problem of keeping things in sync (although I understand you may have other considerations keeping you from doing this)