# How to add and declare new property to class using decorator in typescript (angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-decorator, typescript-decorator, typescript-declarations

I'm trying to add new property to class using decorator. Here is my code

```
function classDecorator<T extends {new(...args: any[]): {}}>(constructor: T) {
    constructor.prototype.newProperty = 'some value';
}


@classDecorator
class MyClass {
  property1: string = 'value1';
  property2: string = 'value1';
}
const obj = new MyClass();

console.log(obj);
console.log(obj.property1);
console.log(obj.property2);
console.log(obj.newProperty); //  error TS2551: Property 'newProperty' does not exist on type 'MyClass'
```

Is there any way to make angular to understand that `MyClass` also have `newProperty` ? Can I do it with `.d.ts` file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a new property to a class using class decorator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41000670/how-to-add-a-new-property-to-a-class-using-class-decorator)

Answer (score 1):

this post resolve your problem:

[How to add a new property to a class using class decorator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41000670/how-to-add-a-new-property-to-a-class-using-class-decorator)