# Is it possible to add new attributes (orient-object paradigm style) using decorators in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-decorator

Is it possible to add new attributes with modifiers using decorators in typescript. I am using **ts-lombok** to generate getters and setters and I want to use this inside another decorator, so when I use a attribute, I will call the attribute like this: `entity.getId()` instead of `entity.id`.

```
class Base {
  @Getter @Setter
  private id: number;
}

@Base
class Entity { ... }

const entity = new Entity();

entity.getId();
```

I found another a solution in the question "[How to add a new property to a class using class decorator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41000670/how-to-add-a-new-property-to-a-class-using-class-decorator)", but it isn't the way I am looking to encapsulate common attributes and without using inheritance.

Comment: Offtopic: getters and setters are not OOP. They are just a complicated way to write procedural programming. Move the code that uses the getter and/or the setter in the class and drop the getter and the setter.